# jQuery .keyup not working with my foreign object tag

Tags: jquery, html, svg, keyup

So I want the user to enter text in an input box and as it is typed it needs to appear in a certain area. I'm using SVG here but as SVG has no wrapping I've been informed that I need to use the foreign object tag to access HTML's automatic wrapping. However if I do that my keyup function no longer works. Here is the input code. Or a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ytktmo00/

```
        <h3>Your Text:</h3>
        <input id="input" maxlength="30" type="text" name="Text" value="Max. 30 characters">
```

And this is the SVG version which words well besides the wrapping issue.

```
<text class="text" transform="matrix(2.4428 0 0 1.5 624.6 550.5599)" font-family="'ComicSansMS'" font-size="41.6368">Your words here</text>
```

If I comment the SVG out and uncomment the foreign object then this is it.

```
    <foreignObject x="78" y="460" width="1100" height="200" style="color:white;text-align:center">
       <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
           <p class="text">Your words here</p>
       </body>
    </foreignObject>
```

And the jQuery for both...

```
    $('#input').keyup(function() {
       $('.text').html($(this).val());
    });
```

Thanks. If you want to see where it is being used then the website is [here](http://dunnrite.co.uk/frame2).

Answer (score 0):

Example in javascript (wait few sec to see effect):

```js
svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
svg.setAttribute('width', 300);
svg.setAttribute('height', 300);
svg.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"); // Not sure about that line

foreign = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "foreignObject");
foreign.setAttribute('x', 0);
foreign.setAttribute('y', 0);
foreign.setAttribute('width', 300);
foreign.setAttribute('height', 300);

body = document.createElement('body');

texte = document.createElement("p");
texte.textContent = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis, malesuada ultricies. Curabitur et ligula. Ut molestie a, ultricies porta urna. Vestibulum commodo volutpat a, convallis ac, laoreet enim. Phasellus fermentum in, dolor. Pellentesque facilisis. Nulla imperdiet sit amet magna.";

foreign.appendChild(body);
body.appendChild(texte);
svg.appendChild(foreign);
document.body.appendChild(svg);

setTimeout( function() { document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].textContent = 'Live example'; }, 5000 );
```

Comment: createElementNS with a null namespace creates unknown elements so this is just html and not real svg in your example. SVG elements must be created in the svg namespace.

Comment: @RobertLongson, Thanks for your attention, I corrected it

Comment: I'm not really sure what I'm supposed to do with this. It doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: Can you put your example on fiddle?

Comment: take notice of the commented bit. See how it works fine as it is besides the wrapping but change things up to the foreign object tag and it no longer works

Comment: I think me too... Weird it doesn't seem to be working off line. Maybe I need to host the files to see it properly.

Comment: Can some one test out http://dunnrite.co.uk/frame for me? I dont know whether it's because of my browser.